# Help needed. Tips for organizing disk space for Win10 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, disk, disk-usage

To begin with, I have no practical experience with Ubuntu or similar systems so please forgive me if I ask the obvious questions.

I am intending to buy a new laptop (no OS preinstalled) and set up a Dual Boot for Win 10 Pro x64 (retail from Dreamspark MSDNAA) and Ubuntu 14.04. I have read about dual booting and setting up partitions and I think I can manage this but I would need some advice on disk space organization. I want to set up my laptop once and leave fiddling with the disk space alone.

My idea is to set up three partitions (not counting the boot and swap partitions): one for Windows, one for Ubuntu, one for data storage. The OS partitions are intended to store software and OS only, so if anything goes bad i restore the OS and software without loosing data.

So the question is: Is it possible to set up a disk partition so it is accessible with read/write privilege under both Windows and Ubuntu? I intend to access and modify Windows software specific data under Win10 (Ansys, Inventor, MS Office) and Ubuntu specific software data under Ubuntu (Latex, OpenFOAM.)

If my idea is not feasible or not advisable, please guide me with some tips and tricks on organizing disk space for dual booting.

Kind Regards
JJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access FAT32, NTFS and, with extra packages, even exFAT file systems (mostly) transparently from Ubuntu through the file and disk manager.

Accessing ext2/3/4 file systems from Windows is very finicky, but possible.

So, yes, it's possible to share data on a partition between Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Thank You! I will share my experiences as soon as I set up my laptop.